# How to draw custom shape with arc in centre using UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uiview, drawing, shapes, uibezierpath

I am try create custom shape of view with arc in centre, but I am not working with this tools in past.

I create shape what I want but not elegant like need.

What I do wrong?

I am feel where I do mistakes but can't fix it.
How work with this tools, I use this tutorial - https://ayusinghi96.medium.com/draw-custom-shapes-and-views-with-uiberzierpath-ios-1737f5cb975

Result which need:
[image]

My result:
[image]

My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

/// Custom card view class
///
class CardView : UIView
{
  // init the view with a rectangular frame
  override init(frame: CGRect)
  {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  }
  // init the view by deserialisation
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  }
  /// override the draw(_:) to draw your own view
  ///
  /// Default implementation - `rectangular view`
  ///
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
  {
    let padding: CGFloat = 5.0
    let centerButtonHeight: CGFloat = 50
    let f = CGFloat(centerButtonHeight / 2.0) + padding

    let halfW = frame.width/2.0
    let r = CGFloat(11)
    
    // Card view corner radius
    let cardRadius = CGFloat(7)
    // Button slot arc radius
    let buttonSlotRadius = CGFloat(30)
    
    // Card view frame dimensions
    let viewSize = self.bounds.size
    // Effective height of the view
    let effectiveViewHeight = viewSize.height - buttonSlotRadius
    // Get a path to define and traverse
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    // Shift origin to left corner of top straight line
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: 0))
    
    // top line
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - cardRadius, y: 0))
    
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: halfW-f-(r/2.0), y: 0))
//
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: halfW-f, y: (r/2.0)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW-f, y: 0))
//
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: halfW, y: (r/7.0)), radius: f, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
//
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: halfW+f+(r/5.5), y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW+f, y: 0))
    
    // top-right corner arc
    path.addArc(
      withCenter: CGPoint(
        x: viewSize.width - cardRadius,
        y: cardRadius
      ),
      radius: cardRadius,
      startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 3 / 2),
      endAngle: CGFloat(0),
      clockwise: true
    )
    // right line
    path.addLine(
      to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width, y: effectiveViewHeight)
    )
    
    
    // bottom-right corner arc
    path.addArc(
      withCenter: CGPoint(
        x: viewSize.width - cardRadius,
        y: effectiveViewHeight - cardRadius
      ),
      radius: cardRadius,
      startAngle: CGFloat(0),
      endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2),
      clockwise: true
    )
    // right half of bottom line
    path.addLine(
      to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width / 4 * 3, y: effectiveViewHeight)
    )

    // left half of bottom line
    path.addLine(
      to: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: effectiveViewHeight)
    )
    // bottom-left corner arc
    path.addArc(
      withCenter: CGPoint(
        x: cardRadius,
        y: effectiveViewHeight - cardRadius
      ),
      radius: cardRadius,
      startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2),
      endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
      clockwise: true
    )
    // left line
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cardRadius))
    // top-left corner arc
    path.addArc(
      withCenter: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: cardRadius),
      radius: cardRadius,
      startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
      endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 3),
      clockwise: true
    )
    
    // close path join to origin
    path.close()
    // Set the background color of the view
    UIColor.init(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1).set()
    path.fill()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, would appreciate the upvote!

Comment: Your code draw shape but not copy of shape like in example above, radius of your circle center below than need.

Comment: i mean its just the matter of parameters, I have managed to fix mistakes in your code sample. Your shape was not resembling the one from the picture. All you gotta do is adjust the parameters and youre good to go.

Comment: I did tried adjust parameters but couldn't fix that, after few days I am rewrite code, and good result - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090595/uibezierpath-how-to-draw-quadcurve

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these two lines:

```swift
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: halfW, y: (r/7.0)), radius: f, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
//
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: halfW+f+(r/5.5), y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW+f, y: 0))
```

to:

```swift
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: halfW, y: (r/2.0)), radius: f, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
//
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: halfW+f+(r/2), y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW+f, y: 0))
```

And here is the fixed and slightly refactored code inside the `func draw(_ rect: CGRect)`

```swift
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let padding: CGFloat = 5
    let centerButtonHeight: CGFloat = 50
    let f: CGFloat = centerButtonHeight / 2 + padding

    let halfW = frame.width / 2
    let r: CGFloat = 11

    // Card view corner radius
    let cardRadius: CGFloat = 7
    // Button slot arc radius
    let buttonSlotRadius: CGFloat = 30

    // Card view frame dimensions
    let viewSize = self.bounds.size
    // Effective height of the view
    let effectiveViewHeight = viewSize.height - buttonSlotRadius
    // Get a path to define and traverse
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    // Shift origin to left corner of top straight line
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: 0))

    // top line
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - cardRadius, y: 0))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: halfW - f - (r / 2), y: 0))

    path.addQuadCurve(
        to: CGPoint(x: halfW - f, y: (r / 2)),
        controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW - f, y: 0)
    )

    path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(x: halfW, y: (r / 2)),
        radius: f, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false
    )
    //
    path.addQuadCurve(
        to: CGPoint(x: halfW + f + (r / 2), y: 0),
        controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW + f, y: 0)
    )

    // top-right corner arc
    path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
            x: viewSize.width - cardRadius,
            y: cardRadius
        ),
        radius: cardRadius, startAngle: .pi * 3 / 2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true
    )
    // right line
    path.addLine(
        to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width, y: effectiveViewHeight)
    )


    // bottom-right corner arc
    path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
            x: viewSize.width - cardRadius,
            y: effectiveViewHeight - cardRadius
        ),
        radius: cardRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi / 2, clockwise: true
    )
    // right half of bottom line
    path.addLine(
        to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width / 4 * 3, y: effectiveViewHeight)
    )

    // left half of bottom line
    path.addLine(
        to: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: effectiveViewHeight)
    )
    // bottom-left corner arc
    path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
            x: cardRadius,
            y: effectiveViewHeight - cardRadius
        ),
        radius: cardRadius, startAngle: .pi / 2, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true
    )
    // left line
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cardRadius))
    // top-left corner arc
    path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: cardRadius),
        radius: cardRadius, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi / 2 * 3, clockwise: true
    )

    // close path join to origin
    path.close()
    // Set the background color of the view
    UIColor(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1).set()
    path.fill()
}
```