# UIBezierPath, how to draw "QuadCurve"

Tags: swift, drawing, uibezierpath, curve

I am try draw shape using UIBezierPath, but I am not completely understand how need to use "addQuadCurve", I am draw first Curve left from the center cirle hole but can't understand how to draw right edge.

What I am doing wrong?

Result What need:
[image: result that need]
My result:[image: my result]

Code of shape:

```
class CustomShapeOfBottomOne: UIView {

    // init the view with a rectangular frame
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    // init the view by deserialisation
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        
        let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.149, alpha: 1.000)
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let viewWidth = frame.width
        let viewHeight = frame.height - 20
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth - viewWidth) + 10, y: 0))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2) - 35 - 10, y: 0))
        
        // center left edge
        
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) - 35, y: (11/2.0)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) - 35, y: 0))
        // end left edge
        
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: viewWidth / 2, y: 0), radius: 35, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * Double.pi), clockwise: false)
        
        // How to draw this curve?
        
        // center right edge
//        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) + 35 + 10 , y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) + 35 - 10, y: 10))
        
        
        // end right edge
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewWidth - 10, y: 0))
                
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: viewWidth - 10, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + 10),
                    radius: 10,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), // 90 degree
                    endAngle: CGFloat(0), // 0 degree
                clockwise: true)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewWidth, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + viewHeight + 10))
        
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:  viewWidth - 10, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + viewHeight + 10),
                    radius: 10,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(0), // 360 degree
                endAngle: CGFloat((3 * Double.pi) / 2 ), // 270 degree
                clockwise: true)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewWidth - 10, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + viewHeight + 10 + 10))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth - viewWidth) + 10, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + viewHeight + 10 + 10))
        
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth - viewWidth) + 10, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + viewHeight + 10),
                    radius: 10,
                    startAngle: CGFloat((3 * Double.pi) / 2), // 270 degree
                    endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi ), // 180 degree
                clockwise: true)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewWidth - viewWidth, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + viewHeight + 10))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewWidth - viewWidth, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + 10))
        
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth - viewWidth) + 10, y: (viewHeight - viewHeight) + 10),
                    radius: 10,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), // 180 degree
                endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 ), // 90 degree
                clockwise: true)
        
        path.close()
        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Show me example what need change or explain me where I did mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am solved this problem using "addCurve" instead of "addQuadCurve".
code which I am replace

from:

```
// center left edge
        
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) - 35, y: (11/2.0)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) - 35, y: 0))
        // end left edge
        
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: viewWidth / 2, y: 0), radius: 35, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * Double.pi), clockwise: false)
        
        // How to draw this curve?
        
        // center right edge
//        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) + 35 + 10 , y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2 ) + 35 - 10, y: 10))
        
        
        // end right edge
```

to:

// center left edge

```
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2) - 35.9, y: 10), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2) - 35, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2) - 35, y: 10))
    // end left edge
    
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: viewWidth / 2, y: 0), radius: 36.5, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi), clockwise: false)
    
    // How to draw this curve?
    
    // center right edge
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2) + 35 + 8, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2) + 36, y: 10), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (viewWidth / 2) + 35, y: 0))

    // end right edge
```

Result:
[image: Final result]

Comment: That doesn't look quite right. If you look closely at the "indent" in the top center of your shape, there are a couple of thin spikes. Those are a likely a result of your arc going all the way up to y=0. You should drop the Y position of your arc down by 10 points to y=10. (you want your arc's begin and end points to match the end points of your 2 curves.)

Comment: The difference between `addCurve()` and `addQuadCurve()` is pretty subtle. `addQuadCurve()` adds a quadratic Bezier curve with one intermediate control point, and `addCurve()` adds a cubic Bezier curve that has 2 intermediate control points. Both start at the current point and end up at the specified end point.

Comment: Thanks for help, I am change Y position to 10 and radius of circle to 36.5 and all spikes was deleted :)

Answer (score 1):

Diagram out what you are trying to do on graph paper. Draw all the lines, quad curves, and arc segments you are using.

I think that you will find that your arc goes all the way up to the top of your shape, covering the rounded corner that you want. You need to drop the Y position of your arc down so that the start and end points of the arc start at the ends of your inside rounded corners, which are slightly lower than the top of your shape.

Comment: Your are right! I am solved problem, and after few minutes I will post my code, if are you know how more elegant way how solve this problem let me know.